# Where to install JDBC drivers in Hyperic Server

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, hyperic

I have installed Hyperic Server 4.4.0 and I want to use an SQL plugin that connects to an Oracle database. To make this work on the Agent i had to download a JDBC driver for Oracle and put it in `[agent-dir]/bundles/[bundle-dir]/pdk/lib`. I can now run my plugin on the agent using `java -jar hq-products.jar ...`.

Now I want to add it so that it shows up in the server hq. I put the plugin in the appropriate directory and I can add it as a platform service. However, when i try to configure the plugin I get the following error:

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@blah.blah:blah:blah

This is the same error I got on the client before I added the Oracle JDBC driver, so I assume that's the problem here too. But where do I put the JDBC drivers on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the fault was on the agent and not the server. The server doesn't seem to need the JDBC driver at all, which makes sense.

As mentioned, I had put the driver on the agent in `[agent-dir]/bundles/[bundle-dir]/pdk/lib`, but instead it should have been placed in `[agent-dir]/bundles/[bundle-dir]/pdk/lib/jdbc`. The reason why it worked when running it only on the agent probably was because I had added ` to the plugin definition. After having moved the driver to the correct location, I could now remove that.

So, to sum up, the Oracle JDBC driver is only needed on the agent, and it should exist here:

```
[agent-dir]/bundles/[bundle-dir]/pdk/lib/jdbc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can uses `CLASSPATH` env variable or `-cp` java command line setting. In your environment do something like:

```
export CLASSPATH=.:/usr/local/jdbc_drivers/*
```

and put JDBC drivers into that directory.